# ffill on dataframe groupby object not filling all nan data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe with `NaN`s. Below is what it looks like when sorted with `outdf.sort_values(['id','eff_date'])`.

```
         id       color_set      shape_set  eff_date  type
527      35  MONO COLOR SET  REC SHAPE SET  20190318   Add
35       53  MONO COLOR SET  TRI SHAPE SET  20150320   Add
102      53  MONO COLOR SET  REC SHAPE SET  20150521   Add
103      53  MONO COLOR SET  TRI SHAPE SET  20150521  Drop
368      53  MONO COLOR SET  REC SHAPE SET  20170320   Add
56       61  MONO COLOR SET  TRI SHAPE SET  20150320   Add
104      61  MONO COLOR SET  REC SHAPE SET  20150521   Add
105      61  MONO COLOR SET  TRI SHAPE SET  20150521  Drop
388      61             NaN            NaN  20170320   Add
486      61             NaN            NaN  20180319   Add
576      61             NaN            NaN  20190318   Add
556      67  MONO COLOR SET  REC SHAPE SET  20190318   Add
78       72  MONO COLOR SET  TRI SHAPE SET  20150320   Add
106      72  MONO COLOR SET  REC SHAPE SET  20150521   Add
107      72  MONO COLOR SET  TRI SHAPE SET  20150521  Drop
391      72             NaN            NaN  20170320   Add
496      72             NaN            NaN  20180319   Add
592      72             NaN            NaN  20190318   Add
```

I'm trying to `ffill` only on matching `id` and `type` with the following code:

```
outdf[['id','color_set','shape_set']] = outdf.groupby(['id','type'])[['color_set','shape_set']].ffill()
```

However this code seems to not be matching `type`. As below code for `id 61` `index 388` ffiled from `index 105` instead of `index 104`. This code is also only working for some of the `NaN`s as it missed id `72` completely. Below is result of above code I have tried.

```
         id       color_set      shape_set  eff_date  type
527      35  MONO COLOR SET  REC SHAPE SET  20190318   Add
35       53  MONO COLOR SET  TRI SHAPE SET  20150320   Add
102      53  MONO COLOR SET  REC SHAPE SET  20150521   Add
103      53  MONO COLOR SET  TRI SHAPE SET  20150521  Drop
368      53  MONO COLOR SET  REC SHAPE SET  20170320   Add
56       61  MONO COLOR SET  TRI SHAPE SET  20150320   Add
104      61  MONO COLOR SET  REC SHAPE SET  20150521   Add
105      61  MONO COLOR SET  TRI SHAPE SET  20150521  Drop
388      61  MONO COLOR SET  TRI SHAPE SET  20170320   Add
486      61  MONO COLOR SET  TRI SHAPE SET  20180319   Add
576      61  MONO COLOR SET  TRI SHAPE SET  20190318   Add
556      67  MONO COLOR SET  REC SHAPE SET  20190318   Add
78       72  MONO COLOR SET  TRI SHAPE SET  20150320   Add
106      72  MONO COLOR SET  REC SHAPE SET  20150521   Add
107      72  MONO COLOR SET  TRI SHAPE SET  20150521  Drop
391      72             NaN            NaN  20170320   Add
496      72             NaN            NaN  20180319   Add
592      72             NaN            NaN  20190318   Add
```

Any help on how to fill these `NaN`s by matching `id` and `type` is greatly appreciated. Note: if the first occurrence of `id` is `NaN` I would like to keep it as `NaN` as I will need to look up the value from a different data set.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

```
outdf.groupby("id").ffill().bfill()
```